# Grab more out multidimensional array to put in recursive foreach function

Tags: php, recursion

I am trying to learn more about multi-dimensional arrays along with recursive functions so as an exercise I have a threaded comments section. each comment (in the database) has an id, parent id (0 by default, but will be the id of the comment that it is in reply to), and content plus more.

I have followed a tutorial and come up with a half complete solution, however I can only grab a portion of the array's data with my current solution. I want to be able to grab the extra information such as 'authorId', 'commentDate' and everything I have tried thus far to do so has resulted in massive failure. Here is my code so far, the is the recursive function (within a class):

```
    function makeList($parentId) {

    // Need the main $comms array:
    global $comms;

    echo '<ul>'; // Start an unordered list.


    // Loop through each subarray:
        foreach ($parentId as $comm_id => $theCommName) {

            // Display the comment:
            echo "<li>".$theCommName;

        // Check for sub comments:
                if (isset($comms[$comm_id])) { 
                    // Call this function again:
                    self::makeList($comms[$comm_id]);
                }

        echo '</li>'; // Complete the list item.

    } // End of FOREACH loop.

    echo '</ul>'; // Close the ordered list.

} // End of  function.
```

and here is another function that will connect to the database to retrieve comments, and make use of the previous function:

```
    function callCommentList($pid){

    // Connect to the database:
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(HOST_NAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    // Retrieve all the comments from a particular post:
    $q = 'SELECT id, parentId, content, authorId, postId, commentDate, approved FROM comments WHERE postId='.$pid.' AND approved=1 ORDER BY parentId, commentDate ASC'; 
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

    // Initialize the storage array:
    global $comms;
    $comms = array();

    // Loop through the results:
    while (list($commsId, $commParentId, $theComm, $authorId, $postId, $commentDate, $approved) = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        // Add to the array:
        $comms[$commParentId][$commsId] =  $theComm;
    }        

    self::makeList($comms[0]);

}
```

and on another page I have created the instance of the class and called the method:

```
$post->callCommentList($post->getId())
```

Here is the result (the unordered list):
[image]

Ideally however, I would also like to get other information pulled from the database such as authorId etc and display it with the comment(and more). Any idea on how to go about doing that?

Comment: Please consider reading up on SQL injection and the deprecated `mysql-*` functions. Stop using them. This is bad practice.

Comment: @doitmyway I am using `mysqli_` however, I am actually going to refactor this to use PDO and set fetchmode as `FETCH_CLASS` since I have a Comments class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well, I was going about storing items into the array wrong.

In my original code, I stored JUST the comment contents three levels deep, however I realised I could also store other things I needed three levels deeps (the author id + comment date), and did that as such:

```
        while (list($commsId, $commParentId, $theComm, $authorId, $postId, $commentDate, $approved) = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_NUM)) {

        // Add to the array the comment, the comment's author, the comment's date:
        $comment = array($theComm, $authorId, $commentDate);
        $comms[$commParentId][$commsId] =  $comment;

    }
```

which will equal this when the array is printed neatly:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Comment One
                    [1] => 3
                    [2] => 2014-07-06 21:16:19
                )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [0] => Third Comment That does not reply to anything
                [1] => 3
                [2] => 2014-07-06 21:24:12
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => Comment That's In Response To Comment One
                [1] => 3
                [2] => 2014-07-06 21:17:03
            )

    )
)
```

so from there I could easily see that I could just grab the details via the index, so the revised recursive method is as follows:

```
    function makeList($parentId) {

    // Need the main $comms array:
    global $comms;

    echo '<ul>'; // Start an unordered list.


    // Loop through each subarray:
        foreach ($parentId as $comm_id => $theComm) {

            // Display the item:
            echo "<li>";
            echo "<strong>Id:</strong> ".$comm_id."<br/>";
            echo "<strong>The Comment</strong> : ".$theComm[0]."<br/>";
            echo "<strong>Author Id:</strong> ".$theComm[1]."<br/>";
            echo "<strong>Comment Date:</strong> ".$theComm[2];
        // Check for comments:
                if (isset($comms[$comm_id])) { 
                    // Call this function again:
                    self::makeList($comms[$comm_id]);
                }

        echo '</li>'; // Complete the list item.

    } // End of FOREACH loop.

    echo '</ul>'; // Close the unordered list.

}
```

and now I have access to all the array elements I need:
[image]

just need to clean up the code (and use PDO instead for the communicating with the database)